# How can I transfer BLE Beacon RSSI data from Android device to PC in real time?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

I am using BLE Beacons for localization of my android phone. Is it possible when I am receiving the RSSI values on my phone to transfer them to PC at the same time or with delay, so I can watch the movement of my phone directly on PC in real time?
[For better understanding I added simple flow chart of the system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGxfb.jpg)

Comment: Hello Miroslav. Why does this have a `[MATLAB]` tag?

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions.  You should be providing source code indicating what you've already done, what you're trying to do, and what you've already tried.

Comment: Hello, Matthias. The MATLAB tag is because my localization methods are typed in Matlab and they are working good enough for me, but first I am collecting the RSSI values with my phone and then I should transfer all the data to Matlab on my pc. So everything is offline. Now I am trying to make it online and to watch the movement directly on the PC without collecting and transferring phases.

Answer (score 0):

It is common to **solve problems like this with a hosted web service**.  A custom mobile app on the Android phone would report the location of the phone relative to the beacon to a server via a web service API.  The PC could then read the latest reported location of the phone by polling the same web service API.

Comment: Thanks, David. This is exactly what I am searching for but I am not that into with these things. Of course I do not want someone to do it for me, but if someone know where I can find some helpful explanations or examples about it, to do it by myself it will be great. I am struggling with that part.